# Can I use simple regression for means of count data that are not whole numbers?

Tags: regression

I'm a beginner at stats and only need to understand the basics. I've learned simple, logistic and Poisson regression and am trying some problems.

I have a set of count data which have been averaged across repeated samples to create a data set of mean counts (so not whole numbers) for each experimental plot. The distribution of these mean data points is not normal (it is positively skewed) - I think this is expected for count data. My notes say you should use Poisson for count data, but only when the values are whole numbers. I don't have the original data points, just the mean values.

I've tried a simple regression and the residuals look OK to me - is this the right approach? I've attached the Q-Q plot below.

I've also added the scatter plot of count means (y axis) against the independent variable (x axis), and the histogram showing non-normal distribution of count means.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you fitting the model? What does the raw data look like when you plot it? It seems you are using R, so you can easily share this sorta information in your question. By repeated samples, do you mean that the mean represents the average of these repeated measurements per site?

Comment: The residuals don't look quite normal to me.  And of interest would be to see a diagnostic plot for Poisson regression.  In general, Poisson models are "too parametric", i.e., assume too much about the distribution.  [Semiparametric ordinal models](https://fharrell.com/rpo) can analyze count data (including fractional numbers) without binning and without a distributional assumption.

Comment: Hi Shawn thanks for answering so quickly. Yes, the means are the averages of repeated measurements per site - but I don't have the original visit counts, just the averages. When I plot these means, they are correlated with the independent variables. I'll see if I can add some more info to the original question. The means are not normally distributed.

Comment: Hi @FrankHarrell thanks for answering so quickly. Bear in mind I'm a complete beginner just trying to find my way - I can't do more complicated models yet. If I do a log of the dependent variable the residuals fit better at higher values in simple regression.

Comment: The residuals don't look *too* bad, you may be fine with OLS regression, although @FrankHarrell is right that they aren't exactly normal . Taking logs of the average counts would probably correct too far. You could try quantile regression, which is pretty easy to implement.    If this is an important task (e.g. a company might go bankrupt, people might die ...that sort of thing) then i would consider hiring an expert. If this is just a project of your own, then play around! That's how you learn!